# Do I need to install IvyBridge a chipset driver for Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: drivers, intel, lm-sensors, ivybridge

The problem is that lm-sensors doesn't detect more than 2 sensors.

Could be this happen because drivers for chipset are not installed?

Where I can get them? Is it already builtin in linux kernel?

*System: Ubuntu 12.10. Dell Inspiron R15 / i7 / Mobile Intel HM76 Express Chipset.*

Answer (score 0):

Usually you do not need to install *any* drivers manually.

In some cases the drivers for graphic cards are not included or do not work well (enough), but I've never heard of a case of somebody installing the chipset drivers manually.